# Paypal subscption - remove ship to section

Tags: laravel, paypal, subscription

I have used paypal subscription package [srmklive/paypal][1]. I want to remove ship to section.

```
$response = $this->provider->addProductById($data['product_id'])
    ->addBillingPlanById($data['plan_id'])
    ->setReturnAndCancelUrl($return_url, $cancel_url)
    ->setupSubscription($user['user_name'], $user['email'], Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));`enter code here`
```

setupSubscription() redirect to
path:D:\xampp8\htdocs\abd\vendor\srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalAPI\Subscriptions\Helpers.php

enter code here

public function setupSubscription(string $customer_name, string $customer_email, string $start_date = '')
{
$start_date = !empty($start_date) ? Carbon::parse($start_date)->toIso8601String() : Carbon::now()->toIso8601String();

```
    $body = [
        'plan_id'    => $this->billing_plan['id'],
        'start_time' => $start_date,
        'quantity'   => 1,
        'subscriber' => [
            'name'          => [
                'given_name' => $customer_name,
            ],
            'email_address' => $customer_email,
        ],
    ];

    if ($this->has_setup_fee) {
        $body['plan'] = [
            'payment_preferences' => $this->payment_preferences,
        ];
    }

    // if (isset($this->shipping_address)) {
    //     $body['subscriber']['shipping_address'] = $this->shipping_address;
    // }

    if ($this->return_url && $this->cancel_url) {
        $body['application_context'] = [
            'return_url' => $this->return_url,
            'cancel_url' => $this->cancel_url,
        ];
    }

    $subscription = $this->createSubscription($body);

    unset($this->product);
    unset($this->billing_plan);
    unset($this->trial_pricing);
    unset($this->return_url);
    unset($this->cancel_url);

    return $subscription;
}
```

here createSubscription () call:
path:D:\xampp8\htdocs\abd\vendor\srmklive\paypal\src\Traits\PayPalAPI\Subscriptions.php

public function createSubscription(array $data)
{
// $data['application_context']['shipping_preference'] = 'NO_SHIPPING';

```
    $this->apiEndPoint = 'v1/billing/subscriptions';

    $this->options['json'] = $data;

    $this->verb = 'post';

    return $this->doPayPalRequest();
}
```

here when i add // $data['application_context']['shipping_preference'] = 'NO_SHIPPING';
then it will remove ship to section , but i don't wan to change in vendor file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that package has helper functions for this, but in the [create subscription API request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create) you'll need it to set:

```json
application_context {
  shipping_preference:"NO_SHIPPING"
}
```